# Ionic issue - Passing and accessing data between typescript and html

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I'm very new to Ionic and typescript.

I've got the following experimental function code in my papers.ts script:

```
  loadPaper(paper){
    let test = {'name': 'Person A', 'id': 1};

    console.log('TEST', test);
    console.log('paper', paper);

    this.navCtrl.push(this.loadPaperPage, {paper:paper, questions:test});
  }
```

All I am trying to do is pass a second variable called `questions`, with mock data created in the `test` variable, to my `load-paper.html` script.

However, when I load the HTML script, the output is blank when I try printing the `questions` object OR unidentified type error when I try reading the fields of the object.

The following is my HTML code:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{paper.paper.title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    TEST #1: {{questions}}<br>      // blank
    TEST #2: {{test}}<br>           // blank
    TEST #3: {{questions.id}}<br>   // Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
</ion-content>
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

The entire script:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { PapersProvider } from '../../providers/papers/papers';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoadPaperPage } from '../load-paper/load-paper';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-papers',
  templateUrl: 'papers.html',
  providers: [PapersProvider]
})
export class PapersPage {

    private loadPaperPage;
    public papers = new Array();
    public test = {
        id: '',
        name: ''
    }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public papersData:PapersProvider, public loadingCtrl:LoadingController) {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({content: 'Loading papers'});

    papersData.getPapers().subscribe(papers => {
        loader.present();

        if( typeof papers['papers'] != 'undefined' )
            this.papers = papers['papers'];

        loader.dismiss();
    });
    this.loadPaperPage = LoadPaperPage;
  } // close constructor

  loadPaper(paper){
    this.test = {'name': 'Person A', 'id': 1};

    console.log('paper', paper);

    this.navCtrl.push(this.loadPaperPage, {
        paper: paper,
        questions: this.test
    });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PapersPage');
  }

}
```

Comment: in the loadPaperPage, you are getting the data like this: this.questions = this.navParams.get('questions');, or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use NavController to Pass Data and retrieve it Through NavParams

```
navigate(){

this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage, {
 title: ‘Emergency’
 });

  }
```

Then on the Second page User NavParams to retrieve Like this in your Construct
declare Title

```
title: string;

this.title = this.navParams.get(‘title’);
```

then you can Use {{title}} on the view in your second page.

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood you but when you said "second page" did you mean passing from one typescript script to another?

If that's the case, I'm actually passing from a typescript to html.

Comment: Actually, your passing from one typescript to another, you are using the navCtrl.push, it will call another page, in your case LoadPaperPage. But before to use the parameters passed to the LoadPaperPage in the view, you have to get them in your page(LoadPaperPage). You have to use navParams.get('title') (for example), and store its value to a public variable in yout LoadPaperPage, then, your view will display your value. I made myself understood?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class variable for each of the options.  the scope of the variables are only accessible within the function or within `navCtrl`.

I suggest adding public variables to your class for questions, test, and paper and assigning the values to your variables within your function.

That way you will be able to access them with your current template.

I also suggest checking out some of the documentation on [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----)

Comment: I think I tried your suggestion but I still get blank output in the HTML. I have updated my post with the full script.